# ViewModel with reference to object that has the activity context

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel

I'm trying to implement MVVM arch, so I have my Activity and ViewModel and the ViewModel has an Interactor reference which is injected to the ViewModel but in the Interactor I need the activity context so I reference it there.

I read this warning [in the docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html) : `"Caution: A ViewModel must never reference a view, Lifecycle, or any class that may hold a reference to the activity context."`

With this approach the warning from the doc is kind of ignored...

Is this the right approach?

Thanks

Comment: what do you want Activity context for? cannot you use Application context?

Comment: Actually I just need context so I can use the application context but every time I need context in an interactor I should use the app context? 
Is that a good approach, I try to limit the app context uses to when it will outlive the activity

Comment: see [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel.html)

Comment: I missed that reference when going over the ViewModel docs...
I'll do some more reading and if I can't find some other approach I'll resort to just passing the app context.

Thank you

Comment: read the very next paragraph below the quote you posted: `"However ViewModel objects must never observe changes to lifecycle-aware observables, such as LiveData objects. If the ViewModel needs the Application context, for example to find a system service, it can extend the AndroidViewModel class and have a constructor that receives the Application in the constructor, since Application class extends Context.

"`